# Postgresql usage of aggregates and non-aggregate columns, grouping by

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, aggregate

Some things in lecture and in my lab assignment were not explained very well. I am having trouble displaying the correct information.
Here is the database info, simply a reference for you to help me.
[The database tables info](http://pastebin.com/HtfQY1He) 
This is the query that I am trying to execute
[The postgresql php select statement](http://pastebin.com/91QvkSwm)

This results in this SQl error being throwned

Connected to database!
**Query failed: ERROR: column "city.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 3: city.name ^**

Now if I do add city.name into the GROUP BY clause, it returns 4096 rows! I dont want that to happen, the results have to be group by country name which is 232 rows. I simply want to display the country name, city name, and the city with the highest population in that country. City name is throwing me off, Im guessing there is  a more complicated more syntax heavy solution. 
Thanks for any help you can provide.
-Tom Reese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
select
        country.name,
        city.name,
        mp.maxpop
from
        lab6.country,
        lab6.city,
        (select
                country_code,
                max(population) as maxpop
        from
                lab6.city
        group by
                country_code
        ) mp
where
        country.country_code=mp.country_code and
        country.country_code=city.county_code and 
        mp.maxpop=city.population
```

notes:

- This can give you more result/county.
- Your original query doesn't work because in ansi sql you can't return only aggregated or group by expressions from a "group by" query. (As the error mentions)

Comment: ok this makes more sense the professor did provide a example that was very similar to this but it was only on one table, i could not connect the dots. Thanks Lajos

Comment: welcome. There are other methods to achieve the same result, but they are not ansi sql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html In school probably you should practice the learned methods.

Comment: I'm pretty sure window functions are standard SQL. I think your first `where` is supposed to be a `from` and you might want to do something about those nasty implicit joins.

Comment: You are right... When I learnt sql these window functions not existed in practice... :-)

Comment: yeah i fixed the where to a from, every thing is working, here is proof http://imgur.com/gS1mwmf